# Creating docs for dispatched functions using Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, dispatch, multiple-dispatch

I am using the [multipledispatch](https://pypi.org/project/multipledispatch/) package in order to dispatch some functions. I created meaningful docstrings for every function. The code just runs fine.

```
# md.py

from multipledispatch import dispatch


@dispatch(int, int)
def calc(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    """Adds two integers

    Parameters
    ----------
    a, b : int
        Integer to be added

    Returns
    -------
    int
        Sum of `a` and `b`.
    """
    return a + b


@dispatch(str, str)
def calc(a: str, b: str) -> str:
    """Adds two strings

    Parameters
    ----------
    a, b : str
        Strings to be concatenated

    Returns
    -------
    str
        Concatenated string.
    """
    return f"{a} {b}"


@dispatch(float, str)
def calc(a: float, b: str) -> float:
    """Adds two floats.

    The second float wil be transformed from a string.

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : float
        First summand.
    b : str
        Second summand, will be transformed into flaot.

    Returns
    -------
    float
        Sum of `a` and `b`
    """
    return a + float(b)


def add(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    """Adds two integers

    Parameters
    ----------
    a, b : int
        Integer to be added

    Returns
    -------
    int
        Sum of `a` and `b`.
    """
    return a + b
```

However, I am struggling when it comes to create HTML documentation using [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/). It simply doesn't create the dispatched functions' docs. For functions that are not dispatched (such as `add` in my example), the docs are correct. `Sphinx` doesn't throw any error when issuing the `make html` command.

Here's my `md.rst` content:

```
*************
API Reference
*************

.. automodule:: md
    :members:
```

[image: HTML docs]

I'm not sure what really to expect from Sphinx (that is, how should the result look like), but issuing `help(calc)` in a command line window reveals the following:

```
help(calc)
Help on Dispatcher in module multipledispatch.dispatcher:
calc = <dispatched calc>
    Multiply dispatched method: calc
    
    Inputs: <int, int>
    -------------------
    Adds two integers
    
        Parameters
        ----------
        a, b : int
            Integer to be added
    
        Returns
        -------
        int
            Sum of `a` and `b`.
    
    Inputs: <str, str>
    -------------------
    Adds two integers
    
        Parameters
        ----------
        a, b : str
            Strings to be concatenated
    
        Returns
        -------
        str
            Concatenated string.
    
    Inputs: <float, str>
    ---------------------
    Adds two floats.
    
        The second float wil be transformed from a string.
    
        Parameters
        ----------
        a : float
            First summand.
        b : str
            Second summand, will be transformed into flaot.
    
        Returns
        -------
        float
            Sum of `a` and `b`
```

I would be happy if I can get something like this via `Sphinx`.

Comment: Does anything change if you add the `:undoc-members:` option? See the note immediately before this heading: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#configuration

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not changing anything.

Comment: I don't know anything about `@dispatch`, but I guess the problem is related to how decorators work. Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-sphinx%5D+decorator+docstring

Comment: I not sure. The problem might also be that there are three functions with the same name.

Comment: If you remove two of the `calc` functions, does anything happen?

Comment: No, nothing happens, which means that you're right in assuming that the decorator is responsible.